# How to group values by key?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have data in this type of key-value pair:

```
d={'Mary' : 'New York', 'Joe' : 'Jersey', 'David' : 'WashingtonDC',
   'Mary' : 'LA', 'Joe' : 'Seattle', 'Mary' : 'Chicago', 'Joe' : 'Houston'}
```

But dictionary in python doesnt allow duplicate keys. So when i run my code, Python just keeps 1 key value pair for the same key rather than all key value pairs

So when I run `d.items()` I see:

```
{'David' : 'WashingtonDC', 'Mary' : 'Chicago', 'Joe' : 'Houston'}
```

And then of course doing something like:

```
caller={}
for k,v in d.items():
    caller[k].append(v)
```

It gives me:

```
{'David' : 'WashingtonDC', 'Mary' : 'Chicago', 'Joe' : 'Houston'}
```

Ideally i wanted the result

```
{'Mary' : ['New York', 'LA', 'Chicago'], 'Joe' : ['Jersey', 'Seattle', 'Houston'], 
 'David' : 'WashingtonDC'}
```

Comment: The way the data is organized is problematic... is there any way for you to change the structure of it?

Comment: @sushanth - unfortunately it doesn't, because in a dictionary you cannot have duplicate keys. So Python removes all duplicate keys and keeps only 1 key-value pair.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 - yes I can change the structure, just need some pointers on how. If I reverse the order, then again i run into the same issue of Python keeping only 1 key-value pair.